# Making any vector point towards the origin?

Tags: c++, opengl, math, vector

A vector of any value needs to be pointed towards the origin. Can anyone help me with the math? This is needed for my program that I'm making. I'm working with animation, so I have a location (x, y) and a direction vector which is added to the location every time it animates through. I want to make the direction vector always make my object that is being animated always float towards the center of the screen which is (0, 0) in my program. so if my location is (1.3, 0.0) I want the direction vector to keep adding something like ( 1.3 - 0.2, 0.0 ) every animation cycle or frame?

Comment: Do you want the objects to pass through the center, *or do you want the view port centered*?

Comment: In your example, the direction vector points *away* from the origin. Just use (kx, ky) where k<0, and stop using such sloppy language.

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic vector geometry. If you have a location `(x, y)`, this means that `(x, y)` is the vector from the origin to the location. The vector in the opposite direction, meaning from the location to the origin, is simply the vector with the sign inverted, which is `(-x, -y)`.

Another way of deriving the same value: A vector from point `p` to point `q` is the difference between the two points, `q - p`. Therefore, the vector from point `(x, y)` to point `(0, 0)` is `(0, 0) - (x, y)`, which is `(0 - x, 0 - y)`, or again `(-x, -y)`.

Depending on how you use this vector, you may have to normalize it. For example, if you want to move in this direction at a given speed `v`, the length of the vector needs to be `v`. This is done by first dividing the vector by its length, which is `sqrt(x * x + y * y)`, and then multiplying it by `v`. With this, the resulting vector is calculated as:

```
s = v / sqrt(x * x + y * y);
vx = - s * x;
vy = - s * y;
```

To apply this as part of an animation, you will multiply this vector by the time that has passed since the last update, and add the result to your current position. This will typically look something like this:

```
currentTime = getTime();  // system specific function for getting current time
deltaTime = currentTime - lastTime;
lastTime = currentTime;  // save current time for next update

// Update position by adding delta time multiplied by velocity vector
x += deltaTime * vx;
y += deltaTime * vy;
```